# How to split bytes stream into n-bits samples

Tags: python

I have datas of n-bit samples

For example, if each sample is 7bits and

```
1st sample = 1 = 0b 000 0001
2nd sample = 2 = 0b 000 0010
3rd sample = 3 = 0b 000 0011
```

…

each sample is compressed consequently

```
data = 000 0001 + 000 0010 + 000 0011
= [0000 0010, 0000 1000, 0001 1(000)]
= [02, 08, 18] (hex)
```

with data composed of many samples, i want to decode the data into n-bits samples

how can i do this usefully with python?

i cannot simply convert hex to binary, because samples are not 8-bits

Comment: your input is not valid python, please clarify

Comment: the data is list type, with hex elements

Comment: and can you update the question to make this unambiguous?

Comment: sorry, I edited it